# Disable the directory and file listing on web browser.Like we see all listing in source in google chrome

Tags: php, apache, server, indices, directory-listing

I am using PHP as my backend to develop the site, it contains a lot of files and directory. if the structure of my file is visible to the third person it can be easily hacked. So it is necessary to hide those directory form the user view.
I actually search many times on google  and found one case

Disable the directory listing shown in the browsers window if there is no any index.html, index.php like files like this screenshot on enabling directory listing.

> [Image with directory listing enable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6taTf.jpg)

I have successfully get rid of this problem just including these lines in the .htaccess file.

```
Options -Indexes
IndexIgnore *
```

Now, What I actually want is not to show the directory in the source of the browser after inspecting like this image.

> [Directory listing showed in source console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM4s3.png)

But I don't want to show these directories to the user like **https://www.bbc.com/** here I found that only **(index)** not other directories.

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: Where did you create the screenshot ? It doesn't look like it is from a browser

Comment: When inspect my website from chrome or other browser and go-to source. I got these directories.

Comment: I think this is a misunderstanding. Your webserver doesn't list the contents of it. But your index.htm refers to other files which the browser downloads. This is what is shown in your screenshot. There is no point in hiding these because then your site won't work. If you add a lets say secret.txt to your root and don't reference it anywhere the browser won't reveal its existence

Comment: Then In the popular websites like https://www.bbc.com/  why only one index file is shown in the source.

Comment: I guess your last comment was a question ? I don't know where you are looking, when I open `bbc.com` I can see a plethora of resources both in the network or sources tab. They are stored on different domains/subdomains, so you don't see them below bbc.com directly. But they are certainly not hidden. Hiding this kind if resources is pointless because they have to be visible to the browser and therefore anyone can retrieve their plaintext.

Answer (score 2):

How you enable directory listing depends on the type of server you're running. See the examples below and click on each server type for more information.

**[Apache](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/DirectoryListings)**: If apache detects any files in the directory such as:
`index.html`, `index.htm`, `index.php`, `welcome.html`, `default.php`, etc., it will load them and not display the list of files.

This list can be configured with the `DirectoryIndex` directive.

If none of these files are detected, the directory listing will be shown as long as the `+Indexes` option is set for the directory. For example:

```
<Directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/listme>
  Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

**[Nginx](https://nginxlibrary.com/enable-directory-listing/)**: Add `autoindex on;` for the desired directory in your config file.

**[IIS:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731109(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)** On the command line, enter:

```
appcmd set config /section:directoryBrowse /enabled:true
```

Comment: I have turn-off auto indexes and the directory was not shown in the browser's windows But the case is while I right-click on the chrome and inspect it and go to the source , all the files and directory are shown which are needed for the recent page load.